# Intergrate Material UI autcomplete with react places autocomplete

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps-api-3, material-ui

I am trying to integrate material UI autocomplete with the react places autocomplete google library that provides realtime location suggestions based off the the input that the user enters into the text box as the value changes. But the combobox doesn't open.

The location suggestions are accessible via digital keys and in the console, which means that they are being fetched correctly. The main issue I am facing is that the location suggestions are not displaying in the autocomplete combobox. I.e. The combobox is not even opening up to display the locations. Why could this be happening? Here is a short version of my code.

```
  return (
    <GoogleMapsLoader apiKey={process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY}>
    <div className='buy'>
      {isSingle === false ? <div className='map-form'>
      <Box className="region">
            <PlacesAutocomplete 
            value={userForm.location} 
            onChange={handlePlaceChange} 
            onSelect={handleSelect}
            shouldFetchSuggestions = {shouldFetchSuggestions}
            >
                {({getInputProps, getSuggestionItemProps, suggestions, loading}) => {
                    
                return (    
                <Box>
                    {/*Autocomplete box redesign */}
                    
                    <Autocomplete
                        id="location"
                        name="location"
                        freeSolo
                        autoComplete
                        options={suggestions.map((suggestion) => (suggestion.description))}
                        noOptionsText='No locations'
                        PaperComponent={({ children }) => (
                            <Paper elevation={8} style={{ zIndex: 9999 }}>
                              {children}
                            </Paper>
                          )}
                        value={userForm.location}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        renderInput={(params) => (
                            <TextField
                                {...params}
                                label="Enter Location"
                                rows={1}
                                variant="outlined"
                                sx={{
                                    width: 300,
                                    position: 'relative',
                                }}
                                InputProps={
                                    getInputProps({placeholder: 'Enter location'})
                                    
                                }
                            />
                        )}
                            
                    />
</Box>
</PlacesAutocomplete>
            
        </Box>
```

Comment: Hello, what library are you using here? Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates the issue and provide more details to help the community in helping you with your issue.